# Required Mail Headers

Tags: php, email

I have a website in which I send a confirmation mail as part of the registration process.

Some time ago, I had some troubles with the mails I sent since I used no headers (PHP mail function).

Once I put some headers, I've gotten more responses from users, but I suspect that not every message reaches its destination.

How can I be sure that the messages reach their destination?

Which are the headers that can be considered a 'must'?

This is the code of my SendMail function

```
mail($to,
    $subject,
        $message,
            "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
            "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowder\n".
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n".
            "Message-Id: <" . md5(uniqid(microtime())) . "@mysite.com>\n".
            "Return-Path: <admin@mysite.com>\n".
            "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\n".
            "From: admin@ mysite.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers need a white space at the bottom to separate the header from main body. 
Tools like Spam Assassin will give you a big mark down for that.

Also you should use `\r\n` as a line terminator instead of just `\n`

[From PHP.net](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

Answer (score 4):

You should use external library for working with e-mails in php like [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com) , [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). All your problems will go away.

Answer (score 1):

The headers seems quite good to me. The only glitch I see is an extra whitespace in the From header.

I'm sure you already checked it, but just in case ...

```
"From: admin@ mysite.com");
  should be (?)
"From: admin@mysite.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working mail function I'm using for html mail and variable $return is defined to get error report from mail server in case of fail delivery.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
$return = '-f'.$from;

@mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $return);
```

you can see more detail at here [sugunan.com](http://www.sugunan.com/forum/title/1/how-to-send-html-mail-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

The headers look ok, except for the details pointed by @Eineki. Also if you are using Windows you need to send the $to param in the form "user@mail.com" and not "Username ", because it may cause trouble, due to the way the mail() function is implemented on windows platform, the "to" address may be parsed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `Date:` header (its mandatory by [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)) and some mail-clients may assume January 1 1970 as an e-mail date if none is given (and it gets lost between all the other old messages).