# problem sending php mail

Tags: php

I am using simple mail() function to send mails, and everything works fine tile I supply a header info, as shown below:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";    
                            $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; carset=iso-8859-1;\r\n";   
                            $headers.= "From: TESTSITE <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
```

Also, on another note, my cpanel server doesn't show the msg log, so I can't exactly figure out why the mail failed. But for one thing, I am quite sure the problem is due to the inclusion of the header, any ideas what could be wrong and how to debug?

Comment: Looks like there are many other questions similar to yours, try looking at: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609764/mail-headers
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header-php

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko:  cause, if I do something like
`if(mail(....))
{
}
else
{
}`

It executes the else part

Comment: There are very good mail libraries that you could use instead of mail(), just the better ones: Swiftmailer, Zend_Mail, PHPMailer. Check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake: `carset=iso-8859-1` shuld be `charset=iso-8859-1`.

Also due to PHP - mail() manual : "
If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only instead of CRLF (\r\n). Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822."

Answer (score 0):

Well, without any tests, I can tell you that your 2.º line has a mistype:

Content-type: text/html; carset=iso-8859-1

should be:

**Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1**